# How to count number of elements in multidimensional array in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I create a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                 [NSMutableArray array],
                 [NSMutableArray array],nil];

[Array addObject:@"0"];
[Array addObject:@"1"];
[Array addObject:@"2"];

[[Array objectAtIndex:0] addObject:@"5"];
[[Array objectAtIndex:0] addObject:@"6"];
[[Array objectAtIndex:1] addObject:@"7"];
[[Array objectAtIndex:1] addObject:@"8"];
[[Array objectAtIndex:1] addObject:@"9"];
```

And I want to count the number of elements in the array of "7", "8", "9" (object at index 1).
I wrote the code but it didn't work.

```
NSInteger count = [Array[1] count];
```

How can I count the number of elements of only an array(index)?

Comment: Hi, what do you do with `passArray`? I see you add objects to it but no body uses it.

Comment: I'm sorry I took mistake. I edit the code.

Comment: What's the problem in your code, it's work fine my side.

Comment: We don't have any idea whether Array is a local variable, global variable, or instance variable. I'd want to see its declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init],[[NSMutableArray alloc] init], nil];

    [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] addObject:@"test00"];
    [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] addObject:@"test01"];
    [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] addObject:@"test02"];

    [[myArray objectAtIndex:1] addObject:@"test10"];
    [[myArray objectAtIndex:1] addObject:@"test11"];

    NSUInteger array0Count = [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] count];
    NSUInteger array1Count = [[myArray objectAtIndex:1] count];



    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"array0.count=%lu,array1.count=%lu",(unsigned long)array0Count,(unsigned long)array1Count]);
}
```

Hope it can help you.